# Относительные пути axAcroPDFLib

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Задача такая - прочитать файл используя Windows Forms. Долго искал, как сделать без adobe, но не получилось. Теперь мучаюсь.
Проблема такая - при попытке открыть pdf файл, по относительному пути, adobe выдает бесконечную инициализацию. Работает только полный путь ("D:\My works\Programming\Windows Forms\TestWF(.NET Framework)\TestWF(.NET Framework)\PdfFiles\lekcii.pdf"), но это не подходит.
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать относительный путь.
Работаю в VS 2019 все последней версии.
Оговорюсь, что опыта работы с C#, .NET почти нет.

[image: Моя попытка]

Comment: @Simon Этот вопрос полностью на русском. На английском только названия и пути к файлам.

Comment: Не тот коммент скопировал, прошу прощения) Код прилагайте текстом, а не изображением.

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить проблему с помощью "." перед двойными слешами.
Вот так получилось: ".\\PDFs\\lekcii.pdf"